# Installing av lib on Raspi3 failing

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

Excuse me if this is a noob's question, but I am blank if it comes to Python...
I am trying to install the Python `av` library on a Raspberry Pi 3. But all I get is

```
    pi@raspberrypi:~/camera_proxy $ sudo pip install av
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting av
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/40/e6/da37b548e9e1312fb11ffd0f31f8679e1b96d3859790a77e93a113394d34/av-8.0.3.tar.gz (2.3MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 2.3MB 49kB/s
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-Mwk4pG/av/setup.py", line 9, in <module>
        from shlex import quote
    ImportError: cannot import name quote

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-Mwk4pG/av/
```

I already purged and reinstalled all Python (1&3) to no avail. The Raspbian is the latest stable release.

There seems to be a `quote` item not found, that supposedly would be part of the `shlex` library?

Comment: That sounds like your Python library installation is broken, because `shlex.quote()` certainly is a thing. Ensure you purge and reinstall any Python standard library packages too, not just the binaries.

Comment: I did so - apt purge, autoremove and a clean install afterwards.

Comment: You might want to do `find / -name 'shlex*'` before installing Python again, just to be sure.

Comment: I got nil before installation and

`/usr/lib/python2.7/shlex.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/shlex.pyc
/usr/lib/python3.7/shlex.py
/usr/lib/python3.7/__pycache__/shlex.cpython-37.pyc
/usr/lib/pypy/lib-python/2.7/shlex.py
/usr/lib/pypy/lib-python/2.7/__pycache__/shlex.pypy-41.pyc`

afterwards.

Comment: I got it running now by using `pip3` instead of `pip`. Looks like the required feature is not available in Python 2.7?

Comment: Glad you got it sorted! If you don't have software that depends on Python 2 installed, you should probably get rid of Python 2 altogether, as it's deprecated...

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to use `pip3` instead of `pip`.